# Cannot port Lambda function back to normal function

Tags: c#, lambda

I am authenticating to an azure active directory using the following snippet:

```
//Client ID values
string applicationId = ***;
string applicationSecret = ***;

 var client = new KeyVaultClient
 (
     async (authority, resource, scope) =>
     {
         var adCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecret);
         var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
         return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;
     }
);
```

This creates a KeyVaultClient which is authenticated to the directory.

My problem is that when I try to move this lambda function into a regular function, something like this:

```
string authority = "";
ClientCredential adCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecret);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
```

And this is where my problem seems to lie. The AuthenticationContext cannot be setup because the authority string is blank. But how can this possibly work in the lambda function and not outside it, it looks to me like the authority string is blank in the lambda function also? The project in question was created for testing, so it doesn't have any definitions that it could be using. Does anybody know what is going on that allows the lambda to work??

Comment: Because in your lambda `authority` is a parameter and value is provided when it is called.

Comment: So what will the value of authority be when the authentication context is initialized??

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the async part and find out :)

Comment: I cant set a breakpoint in there, its not being hit. That was why I wanted to remove the lambda function in the 1st place. Could it be a debugger problem?

Comment: When the breakpoint was not hit, then most likely the `KeyVaultClient` class did not execute the delegate (yet).

Comment: @Andrey: The authority parameter has to be the URL of the active directory account, it is not given a value when the function returns. Is that what you mean?

Comment: `string authority = "";` => "the authority string is blank". What other value could it have with that code? Does your regular method have the same parameters as the lambda expression? These are the parameters: `async (authority, resource, scope)`.

Comment: @bassfader You got it man, I have to set a breakpoint on a statement outside the lambda, hit that breakpoint, wait a few seconds, continue and then the breakpoints in the lambda are hit. I still cant see where the authority values is coming from, but its not blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your code without the lambda is below

```
public static async Task<string> AuthenticationCallback(string authority, string resource, string scope) {
    var adCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecret);
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
    return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;
}

var client = new KeyVaultClient(AuthenticationCallback);
```

Remember that the `KeyVaultClient` expects a `KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback Delegate` as the argument.

Not sure why you are replacing a lambda (equivalent of call to a function) with inline lines of code - of course the lambda will be called at some later point with relevant arguments whereas your inline code is executed right at the site (which is not clearly specified in your question)

Comment: Seems I have completely misinterpreted how this works, is it finding the ActiveDirectory URL from the client key and secret pair?

Comment: If you want to understand how the code inside the lambda works, then you should post another question. What I have answered is: how to "port Lambda function back to normal function" - based on your question